# Creating Variable with Multiple Tags in InfluxDB2

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxdb-2, grafana-variable, flux-influxdb

How to create a Variable with multiple tags in Flux?

```
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"

schema.measurementTagValues(
    bucket: "AUTOMATIONDB",
    measurement: "${MEASUREMENT}",
    tag: "${RUNID}",
    tag: "CATEGORY".
)
```

The above query gives me no output. How to add multiple tags just like Influx1.x - example - `SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY = "CATEGORY" WHERE "RUNID" = "RUNID" AND "MEASUREMENT" = "MEASUREMENT" AND "DB" = "DB`"

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

`schema.measurementTagValues` can only return the values of a single tag at a time. However, since it's a Flux query, you can use the `union` function to combine multiple `measurementTagValues` results at a time.

Try something like this:

```
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"

tag1_values = schema.measurementTagValues(
    bucket: "AUTOMATIONDB",
    measurement: "MEASUREMENT",
    tag: "TAG_1"
)

tag2_values = schema.measurementTagValues(
    bucket: "AUTOMATIONDB",
    measurement: "MEASUREMENT",
    tag: "TAG_2"
)

union(tables: [tag1_values, tag2_values])
```